# Issues on calling highest() on a zigzag plot

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm on my very first steps on pine and I'm getting a compilation alert of inconsistency by using the function Highest() within my strategy:

*line 20: The function 'highest' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from the ternary operator or from the scope.*

```
zigzag() =>
_isUp = close >= open
_isDown = close <= open
_direction = 0
_direction := _isUp[1] and _isDown ? -1 : _isDown[1] and _isUp ? 1 : nz(_direction[1])
_zigzag = _isUp[1] and _isDown and _direction[1] != -1 ? highest(2) : _isDown[1] and _isUp and _direction[1] != 1 ? lowest(2) : na
```

Can you guys give me an insight on how to properly write this?

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("test", "test", true)

zigzag() =>
    _hi = highest(2)
    _lo = lowest(2)
    _isUp = close >= open
    _isDown = close <= open
    _direction = 0
    _direction := _isUp[1] and _isDown ? -1 : _isDown[1] and _isUp ? 1 : nz(_direction[1])
    _zigzag = _isUp[1] and _isDown and _direction[1] != -1 ? _hi : _isDown[1] and _isUp and _direction[1] != 1 ? _lo : na

plot(na)
```

Comment: Thank you @bjorn! One last question, i've updated the code but when I add both scripts on chart, I've noticed a plot delay between the original V2 and the updated V4. Can you see what might be the issue?

https://imgur.com/a/FNMneCi

Original version V2

    'zigzag() =>
    _isUp = close >= open
    _isDown = close <= open
    _direction = _isUp[1] and _isDown ? -1 : _isDown[1] and _isUp ? 1 : nz(_direction[1])
    _zigzag = _isUp[1] and _isDown and _direction[1] != -1 ? highest(2) : _isDown[1] and _isUp and _direction[1] != 1 ? lowest(2) : na'